# To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 1024 MB

Tags: android, gradle, heap-memory, dex

I'm getting this message when I build my APP in Android Studio:

```
Running dex as a separate process.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
```

I don't know exactly what it means as I'm new in this, and how to fix it. I have a build.gradle (project), a settings.gradle and  build.gradle (APP). Which one do I have to modify and how?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't edit a Gradle file... You  should have a `gradle.properties` file. Do what  it says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M` in the project `gradle.properties`. For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

You can also add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```